# SQL using TRANSFORM to reformat my table in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help reformatting my table using TRANSFORM. I've tried a few things but for some reason it just won't work. Here's an example of what I have to do. Say I have this table:

```
     table1:

| in/out | year   | 
|   in   | 2011-12|
|   in   | 2011-12|
|   in   | 2012-13|
|   out  | 2011-12|
|   out  |2012-13 |
|   out  |2012-13 |
```

I want to reformat this table to look like this:

```
|in/out| 2011-12 | 2012-13 
|  in  |   2     |   1
|  out |   1     |   2
```

The first column is the in/out and the rest are just the years where the numbers under them is just a count of for example how many ins or outs happened that year. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's this:

```
Transform Count(*)
SELECT [in/out] FROM table1 GROUP BY [in/out]
PIVOT year IN("2011-12", "2012-13");
```

Answer (score 1):

The query would be

```
TRANSFORM   Sum(amount) AS SumOfamount
SELECT      [in/out]
FROM        Table1
GROUP BY    [in/out]
PIVOT       [year]
```

Graphically it looks like this:

[image]

You might want to change the field name from `year` though as that's a reserved word and may confuse the database.

Comment: I didn't want the sum of the amounts. I edited my question to make it a little simpler

Comment: You'd need to do something with the amounts - count them, average them, sum them... it doesn't matter as long as they can be grouped into `in` or `out` and `2011-12` or `2012-13`.  The calculation needs to be performed in case you have, for example, two `in` values in the year `2011-12`.  If there won't be any duplicates then SUM will just return the value (as there's only one).  You could change the SUM to COUNT and get the same table as your COUNT(*) solution.